# How to get values and keys from HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm writing a simple edit text in Java. When the user opens it, a file will be opened in `JTabbedPane`. I did the following to save the files opened:

`HashMap<String, Tab> hash = new HashMap<String, Tab>();`

Where `Tab` will receive the values, such as: `File file, JTextArea container, JTabbedPane tab`.

I have a class called `Tab`:

```
public Tab(File file, JTextArea container, JTabbedPane tab)
{
    this.file = file;
    this.container = container;
    this.tab = tab;
    tab.add(file.getName(), container);
    readFile();
}
```

Now, in this `SaveFile` class, I need get the `Tab` values stored in the `HashMap`. How can I do that?

Comment: Already ? It's always so, negative the topic.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

To get all the values from a map:

```
for (Tab tab : hash.values()) {
    // do something with tab
}
```

To get all the entries from a map:

```
for ( Map.Entry<String, Tab> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Tab tab = entry.getValue();
    // do something with key and/or tab
}
```

#### Java 8 update:

To process all values:

```
hash.values().forEach(tab -> /* do something with tab */);
```

To process all entries:

```
hash.forEach((key, tab) -> /* do something with key and tab */);
```

Answer (score 40):

`Map` is internally made up of `Map.Entry` objects. Each `Entry` contains `key` and `value`. To get key and value from the entry you use accessor and modifier methods.

If you want to get `values` with given `key`, use `get()` method and to insert value, use `put()` method.

```
#Define and initialize map;
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("USA",1)
map.put("Japan",3)
map.put("China",2)
map.put("India",5)
map.put("Germany",4)

map.get("Germany") // returns 4
```

If you want to get the set of keys from map, you can use `keySet()` method

```
Set keys = map.keySet();
System.out.println("All keys are: " + keys);
// To get all key: value
for(String key: keys){
    System.out.println(key + ": " + map.get(key));
}
```

Generally, To get all keys and values from the map, you have to follow the sequence in the following order:

- Convert `Hashmap` to `MapSet` to get set of entries in `Map` with `entryset()` method.:
   `Set st = map.entrySet();`
- Get the iterator of this set: 
  `Iterator it = st.iterator();`
- Get `Map.Entry` from the iterator: 
  `Map.Entry entry = it.next();`
- use `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods of the `Map.Entry` to get keys and values.

```java
// Now access it
Set st = (Set) map.entrySet();
Iterator it = st.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry entry = mapIterator.next();
    System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

In short, use iterator directly in for

```
for(Map.Entry entry:map.entrySet()){
    System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You give 1 Dollar, it gives you a cheese burger. You give the String and it gives you the Tab. Use the GET method of HashMap to get what you want.

```
HashMap.get("String");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HashMapObj.get("String");` ?

Comment: You give 1 US dollar in 2022 and you get no burger ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**To get values and keys**
you could just use the methods values() and keySet() of HashMap

```
public static List getValues(Map map) {
    return new ArrayList(map.values());
}

public static List getKeys(Map map) {
    return new ArrayList(map.keySet());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Tab> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Tab tab = entry.getValue();
    // do something with key and/or tab
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

It will work with **hash.get("key");**
Where key is your key for getting the value from Map

Comment: Answer brings nothing new to the table, other answers already explain this and much more.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'string' key of the hashmap, to access its value which is your tab class.

```
Tab mytab = hash.get("your_string_key_used_to_insert");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use iterator to do that:

For keys:

```
for (Iterator <tab> itr= hash.keySet().iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    // use itr.next() to get the key value
}
```

You can use iterator similarly with values.

Answer (score 1):

With java8 streaming API:

```
List values = map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That train wreck is the same as just `map.values()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the following sequence of opeartions:

- Convert `Map` to `MapSet` with  `map.entrySet();`
- Get the iterator with `Mapset.iterator();`
- Get `Map.Entry` with `iterator.next();`
- use `Entry.getKey()` and `Entry.getValue()`

```
# define Map
for (Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet)
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + entry.getValue);
```

Comment: You copied my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using java 8 feature:

```
    map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value));
```

Using Map.Entry you can print like this:

```
 for (Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType> entry : map.entrySet()) 
 {
     System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
 }
```