# How to get Map values?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have defined clusters variable as shown below in java.

```
HashMap<double[],String> clusters = new HashMap<double[],String>();
```

My question is how can I access String values one by one from clusters?
Ex. String name=clusters."?";

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate over each Entry in a Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

Comment: @holgac, find a question with iteration over values. The one you propose asks about entries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get values. keys from HashMap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246821/how-to-get-values-keys-from-hashmap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the values using `Map.values()`:

```
for (String value : clusters.values()) {
  // ... whatever.
}
```

Comment: Thats what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really bad idea to use arrays as keys in `HashMap`, because `hashCode()` of array can return different values for array instances with the same content.

Comment: Then what is the solution if I want to use same arguments?? And access Strings one by one?

Comment: @skozlov This is true, but I don't think it is necessarily relevant to the issue described - irrespective of changes to the hash code due to post-insertion changes, it is still possible to retrieve all of the values using `clusters.values()`.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I want to access Strings one by one. Not all at a time as set. Then?

Comment: @user3553419, see answer below