# Another List inside my Custom Listview with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, listview, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display another list inside my custom listview like in the image below. I have successfully display the first three child(name, sport and town). But when i add the coverage child i got this error 'failed to convert value of type arraylist to string' in main activity.

Error message

```
Failed to convert value of type java.util.ArrayList to String
```

This is the display im trying to achieve
[This is what im trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLRSt.png)

This is my firebase database structure
[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATJEG.png)

I got this code below for my main activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.cusListView);
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textV);

    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Person");
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

    ArrayList<PeopleGetSet> array = new ArrayList<>();

    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        PeopleGetSet arr = ds.getValue(PeopleGetSet.class);

        array.add(arr);

        ViewDatabase adapter = new ViewDatabase(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, array);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

This it my code for Adapter

```
public class ViewDatabase extends ArrayAdapter<PeopleGetSet> {
private static final String TAG="ViewDatabase";
private Context mContext;
int mResource;

public ViewDatabase(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<PeopleGetSet> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mContext=context;
    mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    String name =getItem(position).getName();
    String sport =getItem(position).getSport();
    String town =getItem(position).getTown();
    String Coverage =getItem(position).getCoverage();
    PeopleGetSet person = new PeopleGetSet(name,sport, town, Coverage);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView=inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

    TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView tvSport = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView tvTown = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView tvCoverage = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    tvName.setText(name);
    tvSport.setText(sport);
    tvTown.setText(town);
    tvCoverage.setText(Coverage);
    return convertView;
   }

}
```

And this is my code for Getter and setter

```
public class PeopleGetSet {
private String name;
private String sport;
private String town;
private String Coverage;

public PeopleGetSet() {

}

public PeopleGetSet(String name, String sport, String town, String Coverage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sport = sport;
    this.town = town;
    this.Coverage = Coverage;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSport() {
    return sport;
}

public void setSport(String sport) {
    this.sport = sport;
}

public String getTown() {
    return town;
}

public void setTown(String town) {
    this.town = town;
}

public String getCoverage() {
    return Coverage;
}

public void setCoverage(String coverage) {
    Coverage = coverage;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think there are problem with your model here `private String Coverage;` possible it must be the object with list of strings inside.

Comment: Do you mean a two-level list like `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: The string coverage must be arraylist?

Comment: look to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I mean like this:

```
public class PeopleGetSet {
   private String name;
   private String sport;
   private String town;
   private Coverage coverage; 
    ... default code
}

public class Coverage {
   private ArrayList<String> names;
   ... default code
}
```

Comment: class constructor without params, getters and setters

Comment: `public PeopleGetSet(String name, String sport, String town, ArrayList<String> Coverage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sport = sport;
        this.town = town;
        this.Coverage = Coverage;
    }`
Should i remove this coverage in the line of code?

Comment: If you need the constructor with params no need to remove it. For mapping object from firebase you need default constructor without params, and this one you can use if need

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your Getter Setter class Add Coverage as Hashmap in your PeopleGetSet class. Coverage is not string its array so to read array from firebase you should use HashMap

```
      public class PeopleGetSet {
      private String name;
      private String sport;
      private String town;
      private HashMap<String,String> Coverage ;

      public PeopleGetSet() {

       }

     public PeopleGetSet(String name, String sport, String town,  HashMap<String, String> Coverage) {
      this.name = name;
      this.sport = sport;
      this.town = town;
     this.Coverage = Coverage;
     }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

   public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSport() {
      return sport;
    }

   public void setSport(String sport) {
    this.sport = sport;
   }

    public String getTown() {
       return town;
     }

public  HashMap<String,String> getCoverage() {
       return Coverage;
     }
```

Comment: I change my String coverage to `Map Coverage =getItem(position).getCoverage();`
in adapter
and got error on this line
 `PeopleGetSet person = new PeopleGetSet(name,sport, town, Coverage);`
and here
   `tvCoverage.setText(Coverage);`

Comment: You try this code first, it will run.I have did  in 2 apps working properly.

Comment: I got this error on my adapter this line of code it wouldn't run
`String Coverage =getItem(position).getCoverage();`

 `PeopleGetSet person = new PeopleGetSet(name,sport, town, Coverage);`

Comment: I have told you already, It is not string it is hashmap key value pair.

Comment: Yes i change it to Hashmap. and use this code to settext `  tvCoverage.setText((CharSequence) Coverage);` and got this new Error Message
Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246821/how-to-get-values-keys-from-hashmap

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to inflate multiple views inside one ListView. Here's my example code.

```
public class MyExampleCode extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

private static final int TYPE_1 = 0;
private static final int TYPE_2 = 1;

private Context context;
private List<Object> objectList;

public MyExampleCode(Context context, List<Object> objectList) {
    super(context,layout,objectList);

    this.context = context;
    this.objectList = objectList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_1) {

        PeopleGetSet peopleGetSet = (PeopleGetSet)objectList.get(position);
        //handle code for first object, inflate layout and fill it
    } else {

        Coverage coverage = (Coverage)objectList.get(position);
        //handle code for second object, inflate layout and fill it
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (getItem(position) instanceof PeopleGetSet) {

        return TYPE_1;
    } else {

        return TYPE_2;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return objectList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return objectList.size();
}
```

}

@Edit

Let update your code

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

    List<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();

    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        PeopleGetSet arr = ds.getValue(PeopleGetSet.class);
        Coverage arr2 = arr.getCoverage();

        array.add(arr);
        array.add(arr2);
    }
    ViewDatabase adapter = new ViewDatabase(this, array);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I will add another adapter class? and will not change anything on my existing code?

Comment: Let change source in your adapter for `Object`, override `getItemViewType(int position)` method, add there `if`statement, and move your code in `getView` to the first condition. Now, let create a new layout resource for `Coverage` model, inflate this and fill from `Coverage` object. I've updated my code for your `showData()` method.